# Assume the marginal utility of $u(w)$ is $\alpha e^{-\alpha w}$, $\alpha > 0$ i.e. $u'(w)=\alpha e^{-\alpha w}$, $\alpha>0$.

Tags: probability, utility

> Assume the marginal utility of $u(w)$ is $\alpha e^{-\alpha w}$, $\alpha > 0$ i.e. $u'(w)=\alpha e^{-\alpha w}$, $\alpha>0$.
>
> a) Compute the utility function $u(w).$
>
> b) Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables following the normal distribution
>
> $$X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2), X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2),$$
> such that $\sigma_1=2$ and $\sigma_2=6$.
>
> Compute the relation between $\mu_1 \ge 0$ and $\mu_2 \ge 0$ knowing that the premium for $X_2$ is twice the premium for $X_1$ and $\alpha =0.1$.
>
> c) Under the same assumptions of the previous parts, assume that $\mu_1=1$ and $\mu_2=0,6$. Is it possible to determine for which values of $\alpha$ the premium $\prod_{X_1}$ is higher than $\prod_{X_2}$? If yes, find the values for $\alpha$, if it is not possible, justify why.

**My Understanding**

For (a) since it's supposed to be a utility function we know that $u(0)=0$, so one has $u(w)=1-e^{-\alpha w}$, $\alpha>0$.

Now for (b), I thought that I had to apply the zero utility principle, but I am not sure.

Comment: is something missing from the question? part $b$ just describe something without telling us what is the question isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I just realized that I skipped part of the question. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: what is the definition of premium $\prod_{X}$? I would think is is the expected value so $\Bbb E(u(X_1))=2\Bbb E(u(X_2))$ and from there proceed to obtain the relation between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, but not sure